# How should I link a PHP login script to a mysql database for verification?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am fairly new to the PHP programming language and am working on my first site using the language but I am having trouble with linking the log in page to the mysql database in order to carry out account verification and create cookies. How should I go about this as the code below has some trouble being executed.

```
<?php

$connection =  mysql_connect("localhost","root",) or die("Couldn't connect to server!");
mysql_select_db("irrigation",$connection)  or die("Couldn't connect to server!");

if ($_POST['login']){
    if ($_POST['username'] && $_POST['password']){
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string(hash("sha512",$_POST['password']));
        $user = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '$username'"));
        if ($user == '0'){
            die("That username doesnt exist! Try making <i>$username</i>today!<a href='index.php'>&larr; Home </a>");
        }
        if ($user['password'] != $password){
            die("Incorrect Password!<a href='index.php'>&larr; Home </a>");
        }
        $salt = hash ("sha512",rand().rand().rand());
        setcookie("c_user",hash("sha512",$username),time()+ 24 * 60 *60,"/");
        $userID = $user['user_id'];
        mysql_query("UPDATE 'users' SET 'salt'='$salt' WHERE 'user_id'='$userID'");
        die("You are now logged in as $username");
            }
        }

echo " 
    <body style='font-family:verdana,sans-serif;'>
        <div style='width: 80%; padding; 10px; border:1px solid #e3e3e3;  background-color;#fff ; color #000;
            <br/>
            <form action=' ' method='post'>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b> UserName: </b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type='text' name='username' style='padding: 4px;'/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Password</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type='password' name='password' style='padding: 4px;'/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>    
                            <input type='submit' value='Login'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            <br />
            <h6>
                No Account? <a href='register.php'> Register here!</a>
            </h6>
        </div>
    </body>

    ";
?>
```

Whenever I press the submit button, nothing happens.

Comment: Maybe there's a PHP error, but you cannot see it. Turn on error reporting thus: `ini_set('display_errors', true); ini_set('error_reporting', -1);` at the start. Don't use this in production though. If it helps you to find the error, edit your question to let us know what that error is.

Comment: @Austin Roy the message `That username doesnt exist!`makes it very easy to bruteforce an existing username same goes for the message `Incorrect Password!`

Answer (score 1):

Using the code you pasted here nothing is happening because you have a typo:
`<div style='width: 80%; padding; 10px; border:1px solid #e3e3e3;  background-color;#fff ; color #000;`

That `div` tag isn't being closed here. Just change that line to
`<div style='width: 80%; padding; 10px; border:1px solid #e3e3e3;  background-color;#fff ; color #000;'>` (note the **'>** added to the end) and your Login button should work.

### Edit

To get your code working please fix these issues too:

1. Change `$username = mysql_real_escape_string(hash("sha512",$_POST['password']));` into `$password = mysql_real_escape_string(hash("sha512",$_POST['password']));` (notice the change to `$password` in the beginning)
2. Change `<input type='submit' value='Login'>` into `<input type='submit' value='Login' name='login'>` (adding `name='login'`). This is needed to get the line `if ($_POST['login'])` working.

And as the others pointed it out:

> There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are
>   [**officially
>   deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer
>   maintained** and will be
>   [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning)
>   in the future. You should update your code with
>   [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure
>   the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, i don't know how I missed that. Thanks. Nothing is happening still though

Answer (score 0):

add `name="login"` to your submit button, the `name` attribute is what is used as the key in the `POST` array.

e.g.

```
<input type='submit' value='Login' name="login">
```

The form doesn't have an `action` either but when it's not supplied it should default to the same address but it might be better to remove the attribute completely.

You don't need to echo the html as a string either, you could just use HTML directly and use PHP in the places that it's needed.

You should read up about the deprecation of `mysql_*` functions too.

Comment: "You should read up about the deprecation of mysql_* functions too." Yes, good idea. Might as well start using the improved versions before these stop working altogether.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you forgot `<form action="pageName.php" method="POST">`. Give submit button name like`<input type='submit' value='Login' name='submit'>`.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite your `$username` variable with the password:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(hash("sha512",$_POST['password']));
```

The second line should most probably be:

```
$password = ...
```

And, as already suggested, don't use the deprecated `mysql_*` functions, they will be removed from future PHP versions and your code will stop working. If you are still learning, learn directly with `mysqli_*` or PDO.